# Cordova build android error Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid mobile app for android and ios with cordova, angularjs and angularmaterial design. I use npm, bower and grund to manage and run build task. I could build ios but not android with error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command '/xxx/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 0.919 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /xxx/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/xxx/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true.
```

My environments:

- cordova@6.1.0
- node_modules node packages
- bower_components dependencies with bowers
- angularjs and angular material design

Any help is appreciated.

ps: I run

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

I even tried to remove/add the android but still no luck.

**One interesting observe, If I use a blank project then It will be built successfully for both platforms**

Thanks

Comment: DId you tried a command line build?

Comment: yes. I could build and run in ios but not in android

Comment: Any of your components using anroid Ndk?

Comment: I have not integrated any plugins yet. It is just a pure html with ui design.

Comment: From reading this line from your error `useDeprecatedNdk=true` i think the problem with android ndk

Comment: I think this was generated by cordova build command. It invokes gradle tool behind the scene to build apk.

Comment: Try this way create a blank cordaova project and after import to android studio manullay install angularjs and angularmaterial design componets (copy paste) may be this will work

Comment: yes. I will consider this as final option. I have so many dependencies. putting one by one take lots of effort.

Comment: Take a look at this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529284/cordovalibprocessdebugresources-failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I have node_moudles and bower_components inside the www of Cordova project. After moving my nodejs dependencies from www and and remvoe the bower_components folder and try bower install again it works.

I don't really understand what the cordova build android running behind the scene that cause error when having node_modules inside the www.

FYI I just used npm to manage dependency for my development(karma, grunt, httpserver, ...). It is even better to move it from the www.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding xml namespace for phonegap (xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0") to config.xml

Comment: On what tag exactly to put that attribute?

Comment: put that attribute to widget tag

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was caused by the bower_components. I used the "bower link" command to reference a local bower package so I could work on this simultaneously. But when I tried to build to Android, the build failed with the same error message. 
Using

> bower unlink YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME

(or just removing the 'bower_components' directory) and then reinstalling the packages by

> bower install

fixed this issue.